# Different behaviour of sounds in Android 4

Tags: android, ogg

I have a game in which a "ding" sound is made for each point scored in a game. Sometimes you can score points in very quick succession. In this case I do not allow overlapping sounds so I wait for the mediaplayer's `isPlaying()` function to go to false before playing the next sound.

On every phone I've tried so far (admittedly all 2.2 or 2.3) the result is a pleasing rapid-fire succession of sounds.

But just now I've tried Samsung galaxy S II with 4.0.3. On this machine each "ding" is separated by a long gap. The `isPlaying()` state seems to last twice as long as the sound itself. According to [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) the sound should last about 0.1 seconds, but isPlaying() is remaining true for .28 seconds.

The sound is saved from Audacity into Ogg Vorbis format.

Any idea what's gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use [`SoundPool`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) for playing rapid-fire samples in games as they're uncompressed once and kept in memory. `MediaPlayer` may be decoding on the fly, causing a delay as it gets ready. Not sure why there's such a difference between devices, but I'd give SoundPool a try and see if it improves things.